# Merge the original array of objects into the "as" field after a $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a `hero` collection where each hero document looks like the following:

```
{
    _id:'the-name-of-the-hero',
    name: 'Name of Hero',
    (...), //other properties to this hero

    relations: [
        {
            hero: 'the-id-of-another-hero',
            relationType: 'trust'
        },
        {
            hero: 'yet-another-id-of-another-hero',
            relationType: 'hate'
        }
    ]
}
```

The `relations.hero` points to an `_id` of another hero. I needed to grab some more information of the related heroes, therefore I used aggregate `$lookup` to match each against the "hero" collection, to grab it's `name` (and other data, but project simplified for the question). Here the currently working query, docummented:

```
let aggregate = db.collection('hero').aggregate([
    // grabbing an specific hero
    { $match: { _id } },
    //populate relations
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'hero',
            let: { letId: '$relations.hero' }, //create a local variable for the pipeline to use
            // localField: "relations.hero", //this would bring entire hero data, which is unnecessary
            // foreignField: "_id",  //this would bring entire hero data, which is unnecessary
            pipeline: [
                //match each $relations.hero (as "$$letId") in collection hero's (as "from") $_id
                { $match: { $expr: { $in: ['$_id', '$$letId'] } } },
                //grab only the _id and name of the matched heroes
                { $project: { name: 1, _id: 1 } },
                //sort by name
                { $sort:{ name: 1 } }
            ],
            //replace the current relations with the new relations
            as: 'relations',
        },
    }
]).toArray(someCallbackHere);
```

In short, `$lookup` on `hero` collection using a `pipeline` that match each of `relations.hero` and bring back only the `_id` and `name` (which has the real name to be printed on UI) and replace current `relations` with this new `relations`, generating the document as:

```
{
    _id:'the-name-of-the-hero',
    name: 'Name of Hero',
    (...), //other properties to this hero
    relations: [
        {
            _id: 'the-id-of-another-hero',
            name: 'The Real Name of Another Hero',
        },
        {
            _id: 'yet-another-id-of-another-hero',
            name: 'Yet Another Real Name of Another Hero',
        }
    ]
}
```

#### The question:

What can I add on the pipeline to make it merge the matched heroes with the original `relations`, in order to not only have the projected `_id` and `name`, but also the original `relationType`? That is, have the following result:

```
{
    _id:'the-name-of-the-hero',
    name: 'Name of Hero',
    (...), //other properties to this hero
    relations: [
        {
            _id: 'the-id-of-another-hero',
            name: 'The Real Name of Another Hero',
            relationType: 'trust' //<= kept from the original relations
        },
        {
            _id: 'yet-another-id-of-another-hero',
            name: 'Yet Another Real Name of Another Hero',
            relationType: 'hate' //<= kept from the original relations
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried exporting `as: 'relationsFull'` and then tried to `$push` with `$mergeObjects` as part of a next step into the aggregation but no luck. I tried to do the same as a pipeline step (instead of a new aggregate step) but always end up `relations` as empty array..

How would I write a new aggregation step to merge old `relations` objects with the new looked-up `relations`?

*Note: Consider **MongoDB 3.6 or later** (that is, `$unwind` array is not needed, at least for the `$lookup`). I'm querying using Node.js driver, if that info matters.*

Comment: You need to `$unwind` the array first and need to `$group` it again.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection("hero").aggregate([
  { "$match": { _id } },
  { "$unwind": "$relations" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "hero",
    "let": { "letId": "$relations.hero" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$letId"] } } },
      { "$project": { "name": 1 } }
    ],
    "as": "relation"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$relation" },
  { "$addFields": { "relations.name": "$relation.name" }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "relations": { "$push": "$relations" },
    "name": { "$first": "$name" },
    "rarity": { "$first": "$rarity" },
    "classType": { "$first": "$classType" }
  }}
])
```

Or alternate you can use this as well

```
db.collection("hero").aggregate([
  { "$match": { _id } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "hero",
    "let": { "letId": "$relations.hero" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$_id", "$$letId"] } } },
      { "$project": { "name": 1 } }
    ],
    "as": "lookupRelations"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "relations": {
      "$map": { 
        "input": "$relations",
        "as": "rel",
        "in": {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            "$$rel",
            { "name": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$lookupRelations.name", { "$indexOfArray": ["$lookupRelations._id", "$$rel._id"] }] }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony. I see it merged the relations but with a few caveats: the `_id` was not kept, even after adding `_id: 1` back to the `$project`. Also, all other properties of the main document are missing, but I can't see why. [Here a pastebin of original document, my aggregate and your answer's aggregate](https://pastebin.com/M1psK0eB). I changed the `$addFields` from names to be the entire `relations: $relation`  and `_id` now shows, but then `relationType` vanishes... I'm confused lol.

Comment: Hi I have updated the answer. and also added an alternate method

Comment: It was almost there. The `lookupRelations` has hero A, B, C. The final `relations` ended having the `name` of the last lookupRelations in all entries. See https://pastebin.com/x4zSvAfJ I'm trying to edit your addFields see if I manage to make it work :)

Comment: @RaphaelDDL Have you got the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, nope :( Been couple weeks I gave up on trying to make it work.. So I'm doing a secondary call with to get the data of relation heroes and add by hand to the response. Soon it'll become a callback hell and I'll need to refactor lol.

Comment: Okay but why call back hell. Use async await. :-)

Comment: Hi, I stumbled upon the exact same problem my question here is which one of them is more efficient? or is there a new method to accomplish this in mongodb 4.2 + version?

Comment: @NitishMakhija what's your question

Comment: @Ashh my question which one of the two answers you provided is more efficient query wise for mongo db 4.2 +.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think we should use different name for the *as* field.From there, we can use the following expression the the [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage.

```
{
   "$addFields": {
      "relations": {
         "$reduce": {
            "input": {
               "$reduce": {
                  "input": {
                     "$zip": {
                        "inputs": [
                           "$relations",
                           "$relheros"
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  "initialValue": [

                  ],
                  "in": {
                     "$concatArrays": [
                        "$$value",
                        "$$this"
                     ]
                  }
               }
            },
            "initialValue": {

            },
            "in": {
               "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$$value",
                  "$$this"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note that the *relheros* here is the *as* field.

We really should not [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and `$group` here, before `$unwind` is cheap but [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group) is expensive.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I changed `as` to `relheros` as you suggested in the lookup step and then added the `$addFields` after the `$lookup` object in the aggregation. It ended creating a `relations` as an object, which have as it's properties, the correct properties of what could've been the last related hero. That is, instead of `relations:[{ _id, name, relationType }, {...}, {...}]`, it created `relations: { _id, name, relationType }`.

Comment: I used to do 2 calls, one for the hero document, another for all hero documents in the relations, then manually insert each relation hero into the response with a array.map + array.some. I managed to change this to one call with this lookup, but then I lost the type property, and mongo response now takes 20~50ms more than when I used to call twice and "fix" in node. I wonder if is worthy (performance-wise) to try make mongo add relationType back to the lookup.